# Grails breaks after telling me that files exist in the views folder when they actually do not?

Tags: grails

When I try to scaffold new controller and views for some domain class, Grails keeps telling me that there exists files in grails-app/views/domainName/{create.gsp, edit.gsp, list.gsp, show.gsp}.
However I have repeatedly deleted the whole domainName dir from the views location many times.
What is Grails referring to?  is this related to caching somehow?

Even if I ignore this abnormality and tell grails to overwrite the files even though they dont exist, when i lunch the application, navigate to that controller and click create new domainItem - the browser with think for a minute after which Grails spits the following exception:

`Error executing script RunApp: GC overhead limit exceeded
2011-11-02 10:22:50,484 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]] ERROR core.ContainerBase  - Sanitizing stacktrace:
 - Exception invoking periodic operation:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1337)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1601)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1590)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)`

The app works fine with any other domain class.

Things I have tried:
1. delete the problematic domain along with the controller and views, delete the unit test, delete the generated class files. basically eradicate any known-to-me trace of that domain class
2. run 'clean'
3. make a new domain with the same name
4. scaffold the views and controller for it again (at which point grails ask me if I want to override the views?!)
5. restart STS
6. restart computer

Answer (score 0):

so the problem is in this line:

```
time(range:0L..86400000L) //24h in milliseconds
```

which I still dont understand why. the variable time is of type long
The following two variations also result in memory overflow:

```
time(range:0..86400000L)

time(range:0..86400000)
```